# pallindrome is not copied to next file but printed on output screen

Tags: c, copy, file-handling

I have a file named `fp1` containing different names, some being palindromes, and have to read all names from `fp1` and check if each name is a palindrome or not. If it's a palindrome the I need to print the name to screen and copy it to another file named `fp`.

Here's my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    FILE *fp, *fp1;
    char m, y[100];
    int k = 0, i = 0, t = 1, p = 0;
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\New folder\\file 2.txt", "w");
    fp1 = fopen("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\New folder\\file4.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("error  ");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        printf("error");
        exit(1);
    }
    k = 0;
    m = fgetc(fp1);
    while (m != EOF) {
        k = 0;
        i = 0;
        t = 1;
        p = 0;
        while (m != ' ') {
            y[k] = m;
            k = k + 1;
            m = fgetc(fp1);
        }
        p = k - 1;
        for (i = 0; i <= k - 1; i++) {
            if (y[i] != y[p]) t = 0;
            p = p - 1;
        }
        if (t == 1) {
            fputs(y, fp);
            printf("%s is a pallindrome\n", y);
        }
        m = fgetc(fp1);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
}
```

coping pallindrome from one file to next file

Answer (score 0):

You are not null terminating your buffer before attempting to use the contents as a [string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte). After placing the last valid character read by `fgetc` into the buffer, you must place a null terminating character (`\0`).

A character buffer without a null terminating byte is **not** a string. Passing such a buffer to `fputs`, or the `printf` specifier `%s` without a length bound, will invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

`fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`. On systems where `char` is unsigned, you will not be able to reliably test against the negative value of `EOF`.

The inner `while` loop is not checking for `EOF`. When the file is exhausted, it will repeatedly assign `EOF` to the buffer, until the buffer overflows.

To that end, in general, the inner `while` loop does nothing to prevent a buffer overflow for longer inputs.

In a [hosted environment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function), `void main()` is never the correct signature for `main`. Use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Note that `fputs` does not print a trailing newline. As is, you would fill the output file full of strings with no delineation.

The nested `while` loops are fairly clumsy, and I would suggest moving your palindrome logic to its own function.

---

Here is a refactored version of your program. This program discards the tails of overly long words ... but the buffer is reasonably large.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

FILE *open_file_or_die(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(path, mode);

    if (!path) {
        perror(path);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return file;
}

int is_palindrome(const char *word, size_t len)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
        if (word[i] != word[len - i - 1])
            return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    /*
    FILE *input = open_file_or_die("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\New folder\\file4.txt", "r");
    FILE *output = open_file_or_die("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\New folder\\file 2.txt", "w");
    */

    FILE *input = stdin;
    FILE *output = stdout;

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    size_t length = 0;
    int ch = 0;

    while (EOF != ch) {
        ch = fgetc(input);

        if (isspace(ch) || EOF == ch) {
            buffer[length] = '\0';

            if (length && is_palindrome(buffer, length)) {
                fputs(buffer, output);
                fputc('\n', output);
                printf("<%s> is a palindrome.\n", buffer);
            }

            length = 0;
        } else if (length < BUFFER_SIZE - 1)
            buffer[length++] = ch;
    }

    /*
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    */
}
```